# What is the correct way to refer to a web page that is part of the same website?

Tags: capitalization, internet, quotation-marks

When referring to specific web pages that are part of the same website, should the name of the page be capitalized, put in quotation marks, or both?

In other words, which of the following sentences is correct:

> 1. If you would like to contact me, please complete the form on the contact page.
> 2. If you would like to contact me, please complete the form on the Contact page.
> 3. If you would like to contact me, please complete the form on the "contact" page.
> 4. If you would like to contact me, please complete the form on the "Contact" page.

Please explain your reasoning and/or list your reference (source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form would be to simply use 'Title Case' on the item you are referring to, which is the title of a web page. Title case is simply the capitalization of each word except for short words like 'the' and 'of'. Quotes are also acceptable, but often not necessary; in fact you're probably better off just hotlinking the title to the actual page. A good example of a website that does this is Wikipedia itself.

Comment: Wikipedia does not use title case, it uses sentence case ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style#Article_titles)).